# How to use Unicode characters in mips(qtspim)

Tags: assembly, unicode, mips, qtspim

I'm studying MIPS assembly language in Korea

But I can't find out how to print [Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul) (Korean language) in MIPS code.

To print English text I'd use this:

```
.data
masg1: .asciiz "Print English"
```

I have to use Unicode to print Hangul

How can I use define strings of non-ASCII Unicode characters, and print them with SPIM system calls?

Is the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode supported?

Comment: No idea if the output functions support unicode, but if they do, chances are you will have to encode the bytes yourself. Instead of `.asciiz` use `.byte` (or equivalent).

Comment: It is up to the implementation of the editor and assembler you're using whether they support writing Hangul directly in the assembly source code. My guess would be that they do; it should be easy to just try it. Then you also need an output device that can display it.